# How to deploy silverlight asp.net demo page under subdirectory of another website

Tags: asp.net, iis

I installed screwturn http://www.screwturn.eu/ then create a subdir where I created a website to deploy a silverlight asp.net page demo. In IIS I transformed the directory to webapp.

But when pointing towards this subdir in webbrowser screwturn takes over and return error

We're sorry, an error occurred while processing your request. The error information has been registered and it will be investigated.
Please restart from the Main Page.

Why can't my subwebsite be independant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that `web.config` settings are inheritable. If your application's `web.config` has duplicated the the `<configSections>` part of the `web.config` then this will throw an exception.

Also if you haven't overridden the custom error handling in your `web.config` then the ScrewTurn wiki error handler will kick in.

I'd turn off `<customError>` handling in the ScrewTurn wiki `web.config` and your application `web.config` and that should reveal the true real reason why your subsite is failing.